# how can i replace first two characters of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

lets suppose i have string

```
var string = "$-20455.00"
```

I am trying to swap first two characters of a string. I was thinking to split it and make an array and then replacing it, but is there any other way? Also, I am not clear how can I achieve it using arrays? if I have to use arrays.

```
var string = "-$20455.00"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You dont have to use arrays. Just do this

`string[1] + string[0] + string.slice(2)`

Answer (score 26):

You can use the replace function in Javascript.

```
var string = "$-20455.00"
string = string.replace(/^.{2}/g, 'rr');
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aoytdh7m/33/

Answer (score 3):

You can split to an array, and then reverse the first two characters and join the pieces together again

```js
var string = "$-20455.00";
    
var arr = string.split('');
    
var result =  arr.slice(0,2).reverse().concat(arr.slice(2)).join('');

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

---

try using the "slice" method and string concatenation:

```
stringpart1 = '' //fill in whatever you want to replace the first two characters of the first string with here
string2 = stringpart1 + string.slice(1)
```

edit: I now see what you meant by "swap". I thought you meant "swap in something else". Vlad's answer is best to just switch the first and the second character.

Note that string[0] refers to the first character in the string, and string[1] to the second character, and so on, because code starts counting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "$-20455.00";
// Reverse first two characters
var reverse = string.slice(0,2).split('').reverse().join('');
// Concat again with renaming string
var result= reverse.concat(string.slice(2));

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let finalStr = string[1] + string[0] + string.slice(2); //this will give you the result
```

Comment: Add some explanation, even though your code is explanatory